# android: service layout not showing any TextView in some devices

Tags: java, android, textview

I am using `Service` to show a overlay `View` even if my app closed. but this layout not showing any `TextView`. in android studio Preview, my layout is like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

but after running in some devices:

[image]

all of `TextView`s not showing in some device. but other views showing.

portion of my code is here:

```
public class FloatingWindowServices extends Service {
    ...

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      context = this;
      handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_service_layout, null);

      findViews();
      initialize();
      initButtonClicks();
      moveView();

      return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    ...
  }
```

I change `compileSdkVersion` and app `style` as someone mentioned in another answers but I don't see any change.

Answer (score 0):

I use `android:textColor=""` attribute for `TextViews` and now worked properly.
Idon't know why default text color not wor in som devices.